# Why does my sum suddenly decrease?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a program that tracks the number of items and cost of the items that you place in a shopping bag and then prints out the number of items, total cost of the items, cost + tax, and average.

When I run the program and I continue to add items it will calculate everything accurately, but then suddenly the total cost will drop down. ex: i add 2 items at 10 dollars each it prints: Items: 2 Total Cost: 20, but then I will add 1 item at 5 dollars and it will print: Items: 3 Total Cost: 15 rather than 25.

I've tried running it multiple times. It seems like if I keep adding items at 10 dollars it is accurate, but if I change it up, the total cost decreases. It seems some what random as far as when the value decreases.

I thought maybe there was some issue with using float, but I can't find anything to verify that.

Here is the shopping bag class

```
public class ShoppingBag {

    public float taxRate;
    public int items;
    public float cost;
    public float average;
    public float totalCost;
    public float finalCost;

    public ShoppingBag(float taxRate)
    {
        this.taxRate = taxRate;
    }

    public void place(int newitems, float newcost)
    {
        items = newitems;
        cost = newcost;

        cost = items * cost;
    }

    public int getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public float getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }

    public float getTotal()
    {
        finalCost = cost + (cost * taxRate);
        return finalCost;
    }

    public float getAverage()
    {
        average = finalCost/items;
        return average;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return("Items: " + items + " Cost: " + cost + " Final cost: " + finalCost + " Average cost: " + average);
    }
}
```

Here is my main program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShoppingBagTracker {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        float taxRate, cost;
        int items, newItems, choice;
        String receipt;
        String menu = ("1. Add items" +
        "2. Get receipt"
        + "3. Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter the sales tax rate: ");
        taxRate = in.nextFloat();
        ShoppingBag myBag = new ShoppingBag(taxRate);

        items = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println(menu);
            choice = in.nextInt();

            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter cost of item: ");
                    cost = in.nextFloat();     

                    System.out.print("Enter number of items: ");
                    newItems = in.nextInt();
                    items = items + newItems;

                    myBag.place(items, cost);
                    myBag.getItems();
                    myBag.getCost();
                    myBag.getTotal();
                    myBag.getAverage();
                    break;
                case 2:
                   receipt = myBag.toString();
                   System.out.println(receipt);
                   break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("That is not an option");      
            }
        }while(choice != 3);            
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `place` method overwrites the previous cost.

So when you call :

`myBag.place(items, cost);`

the number of items is correct (since you update it before the call), but the previous cost is lost :

```
public void place(int newitems, float newcost)
{
    items = newitems;
    cost = newcost;

    cost = items * cost;
}
```

You should probably change it to :

```
public void place(int newitems, float newcost)
{
    items += newitems;
    cost += newitems * newcost;
}
```

And pass to it just the new items count :

```
myBag.place(newitems, cost);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the line

```
cost = items * cost;
```

cost is the cost of the most recent item added ($5) times the number of items (3), so cost is assigned 3*$5 => $15.

You will need to, either keep track of the prices of all the items added to the shopping cart, or keep a running total of the cost and add the cost of the items being added.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShoppingBag.place(int,float)` method doesn't add the new items and cost to the bag. It *replaces* what's in the bag, so the contents of the bag at any one time are only what you provided in the most recent call to `place`.

In the `main` method, you're incrementing `items` before calling `place`, but then `place` multiplies the incremented value of `items` by only the most recent value of `cost`.

Also, these two lines in your `main` method have no effect, since the called methods just return the existing value of a field, and you never assign the returned value to anything:

```
  myBag.getItems();
  myBag.getCost();
```